Nuxt Page Stuck in Infinite Loading with Subsequent 404 Errors and sock errors
Environment

OS: macOS 14.4 (Apple M3 Pro)
Node.js: v20.18.1
Package Manager: pnpm 9.15.1
Nuxt Version: 3.16.0
Memory: 18 GB
Devbox Version: 0.13.7

Description
In a monorepo setup using devbox, the Nuxt application gets stuck in an infinite loading state. The issue is intermittent and more likely to occur after the application has been running for some time. Initially works on startup but begins to fail later.
Symptoms

Initial State:

Application shows Nuxt green loading page indefinitely
No progress or rendering occurs


After Some Time:

Console shows 404 errors:

{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "statusMessage": "Cannot find any path matching /.",
  "stack": []
}



On Page Reload:


CopyError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/var/folders/06/1h5mvmpn75s583rcsgphnxm80000gn/T/nitro/worker-90198-2.sock'
Additional Context

Issue persists across system reformats
Other team members can run the same code without issues
Git bisect confirms code worked in previous commits
Using devbox for development environment management

Related Issues
I've investigated these related issues, but none solved my specific case:

#19679 - Similar socket-related issues
#26343 - Nitro worker handling
#25981 - Similar 404 errors

Expected Behavior

Page should render consistently without 404 errors
No infinite loading states
Socket file should be properly accessible

What I've Tried

Permission Fixes:


Applied chmod 777 and other permission levels


Cache Clearing:


Cleared Nuxt cache
Cleared npm/pnpm cache


System Level Fixes:


Increased system file limits:
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000


Multiple fresh git clones
Complete system reformat
Port conflict checks (ran devbox services down)



Which way was used for install Node.js? Try to use brew install
Remove current project and pull from remote git and try to fresh boot
Check for existing all required files, such as .env
If u have installed docker, try to boot project there, maybe something wrong with your Mac configuration
Hope, something will help u :)


Thanks for your suggestions! Let me clarify:


Node.js is managed via devbox.json, ensuring team-wide version consistency. Since I'm the only one with this issue, it's unlikely a Node installation problem.


Already tried:



Complete system reformat
Fresh git clones
Issue persists across fresh installs


Using devbox, not Docker, for environment management. The same setup works for other team members.

The issue seems socket-specific on my system, working initially but failing over time. Any suggestions about socket handling or Nuxt/Nitro worker behavior?

Okay, team members also have a Mac OS or not? Hope, someone have if not it can be as a potential problem...

yes, everyone have a Mac
